# Exception Type: NoReverseMatch Exception Value: 'orders' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, web

I'm newbie in django and now I'm studiyng by book from Antonio Mele "Django_3_By_Example_Build_powerful_and_reliable_Python_web_applications"

I have a question:
When I try to pass into cart_detail from the item description page I receive a mistake:
Exception Value: 'orders' is not a registered namespace
full track below:

```
    Environment:

    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/
 
    Django Version: 3.0.14
    Python Version: 3.11.2
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django_extensions',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'cart.apps.CartConfig',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop.apps.ShopConfig'\]
    Installed Middleware:
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'\]

    Template error:
    In template C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\myshop\\shop\\templates\\shop\\base.html, error at line 0
    'orders' is not a registered namespace
    1 : {% load static %}
    2 : \<!DOCTYPE html\>
    3 : \<html\>
    4 :   \<head\>
    5 :     \<meta charset="utf-8" /\>
    6 :     \<title\>{% block title %}My shop{% endblock %}\</title\>
    7 :     \<link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet"\>
    8 :   \</head\>
    9 :   \<body\>
    10 :     \<div id="header"\>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\urls\\base.py", line 72, in reverse
extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict\[ns\]

During handling of the above exception ('orders'), another exception occurred:
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 115, in \_get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 113, in \_get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, \*callback_args, \*\*callback_kwargs)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\myshop\\cart\\views.py", line 34, in cart_detail
return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
return template.render(context, request)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\backends\\django.py", line 61, in render
return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\base.py", line 171, in render
return self.\_render(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\base.py", line 163, in \_render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\base.py", line 936, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
return compiled_parent.\_render(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\base.py", line 163, in \_render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\base.py", line 936, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\base.py", line 936, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\template\\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "C:\\Python\\django-sites\\myshop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\urls\\base.py", line 83, in reverse
raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)

> Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /cart/
> Exception Value: 'orders' is not a registered namespace
```

my main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns = [
         path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
         path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
         path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
     ]
    
    if settings.DEBUG:
         urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my app/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

    app_name = 'cart'
    
    urlpatterns = [
         path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
         path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
         path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
     ]
```

my base.html of the main template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}My shop{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <a href="/" class="logo">My shop</a>
    </div>
    <div id="subheader">
      <div class="cart">
        {% with total_items=cart|length %}
          {% if total_items > 0 %}
            Your cart:
            <a href="{% url "cart:cart_detail" %}">
              {{ total_items }} item{{ total_items|pluralize }},
              ${{ cart.get_total_price }}
            </a>
          {% else %}
            Your cart is empty.
          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my app/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from shop.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 override_quantity=cd['override'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


@require_POST
def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],
                                                                   'override': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

I leave some more of the track here. Maybe it will be helpful:

```
C:\Python\django-sites\myshop\myshop\cart\views.py in cart_detail
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart}) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
cart    
<cart.cart.Cart object at 0x000001D4278347D0>
item    
{'price': Decimal('21.00'),
 'product': <Product: Powder tea>,
 'quantity': 25,
 'total_price': Decimal('525.00'),
 'update_quantity_form': <CartAddProductForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(quantity;override)>}
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/cart/'>
```

Please help me. I have no idea how to solve this problem

I have tried to change urlpatterns, but i don't know where did it come from this namespace 'orders"

Comment: The `<a href="{% url ">` does not make much sense, it seems like your code fragment is "broken".

Comment: `<a href="{% url ">` seems like you didn't close the tag and didn't pass any URL name inside of it